# Variance along the regression line

Tags: regression, variance, covariance

I have two random variables $X$ and $Y$ of unknown distribution which I sample $n$ times to get a set of $n$ random points. I do simple linear regression on this set and arrive at an equation for a fitted line defined in terms of the covariance of $X$ and $Y$, variance of $X$ and the sample-average of $X$ and $Y$. See first image.

I am now interested in the distribution of $X$ and $Y$ relative to the fitted line. In particular I am interested in something like the variance along the fitted line. With this I mean something like taking the data set and rotating it (around an arbitrary point) so that the regression line now is parallel to the x axis. See second image. I then imagine projecting the data points down to the x axis and doing a simple variance measure on this data.

I have derived formulas for this process but they do not look very convincing. Therefore I am wondering if there is some standard way of achieving this or something like what I have described. I have used the covariance measure, but it does not seem to have the isotropic property I require.

[image: Original data points.]

[image: Rotated data points.]

Comment: The best approach is to use the terminology from your field but explicitly define--or at least illustrate--your terms. (In my first comment I listed those where definitions could be helpful.) Please do not attempt to use statistical terms unless you are thoroughly familiar with them; that would only confuse everybody. Your last comment looks like a good approach: now, for the first time, we learn you are talking about pixels. That's progress!  Incidentally, if you are just looking to characterize ridges in a digital elevation model, check out http://gis.stackexchange.com/search?q=ridge+DEM.

Comment: I am not actually using pixels but it is a close enough analogy. For completeness, I am doing research on triangulation of images. I will return with an illustration. I think that is the bottom line mistake. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Thank you for the edits (+1).  Because they appear completely to have changed the question, I removed most of our previous comments because they would likely just slow down and confuse readers. While you're waiting for answers you might like to investigate keywords on this site including "errors-in-variables" regression, "Deming regression," and (especially) "PCA"; and you would certainly want to make sure you understand issues like the distinction between regressing $Y$ on $X$ and regressing $X$ on $Y$.

Comment: I could accept this as an answer. What you mention is precisely relevant and renders my own approach obsolete.

Comment: Beautiful charts! :-)